# OpenOCD debugger in Eclipse Neon 4.6.2 Error in final launch sequence

Tags: stm32, debugging, eclipse, st-link, openocd

I have been struggling with OpenOCD debugger under Eclipse Neon 4.6.2. Whenever I run the debug configuration I receive below given error message

[image]

I have been attempting to debug the STM32F417VGT6 MCU. My debug configuration setting is following

**Main tab**

[image]

**Debugger tab**

[image]

**Startup tab**

[image]

**Source tab**

[image]

**Common tab**

[image]

Have anybody ever had similar problem? Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Please add actual console output. 
Another suggestion would be to try performing flash-erase and re-flashing via ST-Link utility to verify, that the board is actually flashable and that the error is indeed with eclipse/openocd combination